# Expect an observable to fail in a test in Angular / Karma / Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a component that eventually calls a bunch of HTTP services via successive `switchMap` to fetch data from backends.

I want to test the error handling part. The app has a global error handling (ErrorHandler) and a local error handling via catchError.

The method to test looks like this one :

```
  public methodUsingObservable() {
    this.someRequest()
      .pipe(catchError((error) => this.handleError(error)))
      .subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

Handle error check if the error is linked to the business action, and throw it again to be processed by the global handler

```
handleError(error) {
    checkLocally(error);
    return throwError(error);
  }
```

For my test, I mock `someRequest` with `throwError` to mock an issue with backend call

```
  it('should handle the error when one occurs', fakeAsync(() => {
    const service: MachinService = TestBed.get(MachinService);
    spyOn(service,'someRequest').and.returnValue(throwError(new Error("Failing HTTP call")));
    spyOn(service,'handleError').and.callThrough();


    service.methodUsingObservable();
    tick();

    expect(service.methodUsingObservable).toThrowError();
    expect(service.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }));
```

However, no matter how I do spy and expect on something, Karma keeps considering the test is a failure because the subscription, as actually expected, throw an unhandled error.

I have tried with :

```
expect(service.methodUsingObservable).toThrowError();
expect(service.methodUsingObservable()).toThrowError();
expect(() => service.methodUsingObservable()).toThrowError();
```

But none seems to teach the system to accept the test as successful, and the test fails.

```
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 10.0.0) MachinService should handle the error when one occurs FAILED
    Error: Failing HTTP call
        at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/shared/services/machin.service.spec.ts:12:64)
    ...
```

How can I mark the test as passed in these conditions?

Comment: You're actually handling error properly, but your subscription doesn't catch it eventually.  try to add empty error callback to your subscription as a second parameter: `.subscribe(console.log, () => {});`

Comment: if you could create a demo somewhere, i would try it myself

Comment: Also i don't think that you need `fakeAsync` and `tick()`

Comment: Not catching the error at this point is the actual behavior wanted, the core app wants to catches all exception with a global `MyExceptionHandler implements ErrorHandler`. Adding the error callback in the subscribe, the error does not go to the Handler. I added a catchError to intercept any recognizable business exception and display a message to the user, but then the error continues

Comment: Can you confirm you're using Jasmine version 3.* ?

Comment: Does a solution has been found ?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is to just remove the `catchError` and actually handle the error in the subscribe without even having to throw an error:

```
subscribe(
    (success)=>{},
    (error)=>checkLocally(error))
)
```

This way you will be able to `returnValue(throwError())` in the `Spy` and `fakeAsync` will not complain as the error will be handled.